# Reinstall Mac Messages

Tags: macos, mac

I was hacking around in OS X and got the native Messenger app out of sorts. **I'd like to get back to a clean state with Messages in order to setup my iCloud account again.**

After changing a password, iChats were no longer updating locally. After using all the how-tos I could find I went with running [AppCleaner](http://appcleaner.en.softonic.com/mac) on Messages, deleting everything but the actual application. The idea is it'd be back to a neutral state and ready to setup an account again.

It's now in a state that won't load anything of interest:

[image: Dead messenger app]

I've tried `cp -Rf /Users/user/Library/Messages` after a `sudo su` as well as copied plists from `/Users/user/Library/Preferences` related to iChat and iMessage. That didn't do the trick. There are files in `/Users/user/Library/Messages` as expected, just nothing loads and preferences is empty.

I ran through the advice below and see these errors after the `killall`:

```
10/14/14 12:39:58.116 PM Messages[32851]: Failed to connect (view) outlet from (IASetupManager) to (NSView): missing setter or instance variable
10/14/14 12:40:08.041 PM com.apple.iCloudHelper[33017]: objc[33017]: Class FALogging is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyCircle.framework/Versions/A/FamilyCircle and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyNotification.framework/Versions/A/FamilyNotification. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
10/14/14 12:40:09.131 PM Messages[32851]: [AOSAccounts] : [iCloudConfigurationDelegate] : __73-[iCloudConfigurationDelegate completeSetupWithResponse:account:handler:]_block_invoke - Account save failed: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The application is not permitted to access iCloud accounts" UserInfo=0x60000007d240 {NSLocalizedDescription=The application is not permitted to access iCloud accounts}
10/14/14 12:40:48.765 PM CoreServicesUIAgent[25741]: unexpected message <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x7fff7bca2c60> { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x7fff7bca2f70> { length = 18, contents = "Connection invalid" }
}>
10/14/14 12:40:49.348 PM sandboxd[529]: ([776]) storeuid(776) deny mach-lookup com.apple.dock.server
```

I'm not sure if there is a permissions issue that I could address, but I had recently updated my accounts.

**Please Note:** I've received [not enough traction](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/3126/mjb?tab=questions) when asking questions on Ask Different, so please keep appropriately super-user-ish questions here whenever possible.

Comment: I don´t understand what do you want! Do you want to reinstall osx messenger? Do you want to reset messenger? What do you have done to get these state? Please give us more details ...

Comment: OS X questions are fine here, so we won't migrate them unless you want us to.

Comment: I don't understand what you said you tried. Where did you copy those things to/from? Have you tried restoring all the Messages-related files from Time Machine?

Comment: Added more context! Thanks. I do have a Time Machine backup, but I didn't want to restore the issue mentioned above. A reinstallation of just Messages would be ideal.

Comment: What kind of OSX version do you use? Do you mean iChat oder iMessage? Do you set up an account into message preferences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an OSX application is on a weired state the best thing is to "reset" the application by deleting preference file. This file are located under ~/Library/Preferences. After deleting please execute `killall cfprefsd` to clear the preference cache. Maybe it is neccessary to delete the application related files (like databases and so on) in ~/Library/Application Support.

After all: The best thing is to use your time machine backup. I hope you got one.

Comment: Thanks for those notes. I deleted related preferences (`grep -i` chat), ran the `killall` and see some new errors in the Console. I'll add them above.

Comment: So I recovered (finally)! The time machine backup was part one, but the odd portion was I had to go into my phone, go to `Settings > Messages > Send & Receive`. It showed no emails in there, then errors, then came back listening all my accounts. BOOM - all set now. FYI and points still go to you UsersUser.